# How to configure WkWebView in xamarin.forms iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

Recently, I can't publish my new app to App Store due to the following error:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no
> longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and
> reliability. Learn more
> (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

Question 1, what is UIWebView and WkWebView? I can't even find a single word "UIWebView" in my project, how Apple knows I'm using it? The pages that I used are all xamarin based and Content Page only. You may refer to the code below in my xaml file.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" >
    <StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

That's it, no keyword "UIWebView".

Question 2, how to I set my entire project to WkWebView? I can't find any option in the settings page.

I've tried adding "--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type" to Additional mtouch arguments in the iOS Build but no effect at all. Is there any other way? I just want to publish my app...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems an existing issue of Xamarin.forms on iOS .

1. Make sure that the version Xamarin.Forms is 4.7 or higher and Xamarin.iOS is 13.10.0.17 or higher.
2. Change the Linker Behavior to SDK Only or Link All and then add the
   additional arguments: `--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type`
   Please check all of these have been set under the release
   configuration and iPhone platform.

For more details you could refer
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for reply. My Xamarin.Forms is already updated to 4.8.0.1560 and my Xamarin.iOS is 14.0.0. I also added the additional arguments. But still getting the same result. Is there any possible place that I might missed?

Comment: You could follow this thread https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12217 .